# Examples of topological spaces in which the converse of the sequence lemma holds, but is not metrizable

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metrizability

From Munkres,

> Let X be a topological space; let $ A \subset X$. If there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$; the converse holds if $X$ is metrizable.

Of course the converse holds if $X$ is metrizable, but I'm sure that isn't an equivalent statement. I want to know (if any) counterexamples of a non-metrizable space $X$ where the sequence lemma holds. I'm suspecting $\mathbb{R}_l$, but I have no idea on how to show the converse.

Comment: In case you are really looking for further examples, where it holds: spaces with this property are called "*Frechet spaces*". In particular, first countable spaces have this property. I don't know what you mean by $\mathbb R_l$. Isn't it first countable?

Comment: Yes, I was actually looking for further examples. I should edit the title, thanks for letting me know. Also, I wanted to say that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is not metrizable, so this would be an example of a space in which the converse holds, but is not metrizable.

Comment: Is $\mathbb R_l$ the Sorgenfrey line? Then it serves as an example, since it is first countable.

Comment: The converse holds in a weaker sense, i.e., if $X$ is first countable. Anyways, just take any non-metrizable space for a counterexample...